# Apache jena SPARQL query example wrong

Tags: sparql

At the OPTIONALs and Order Dependent Queries section of:

https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_optionals.html

it is suggested the query:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX vCard: <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#>

SELECT ?name
WHERE
{
  ?x a foaf:Person .
  OPTIONAL { ?x foaf:name ?name }
  OPTIONAL { ?x vCard:FN  ?name }
}
```

I used the same data they posted at the example and Apache Jena from:

https://hub.docker.com/r/stain/jena-fuseki

After uploading that data (the RDF code below "With an example set of data in which every combination of values exist:") and running the query I get no results yet the example shows a non empty result set.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you remove the two OPTIONAL lines, you get results?

Comment: how exactly did you load the data? And which data? The data which is provided in the tutorial below the query I hope? what does a simple `select * {?s ?p ?o}` return?

Comment: Through the Edit tab I copy/paste the code. Strangely, I rebooted the docker container and copy/pasted again an now it shows the error:  "Parse error: [line: 2, col: 1 ] Broken IRI (newline): rdf:RDF"

Comment: that looks like a bug in the web interface or it doesn't accept RDF/XML. You can convert the RDF/XML data first by using e.g. this online converter: https://www.easyrdf.org/converter - convert it to N-Triples format and put that text into the Edit tab.